# STL list, delete all the odd numbers

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to learn how to work with STL and tried to write a function which will recieve a refference to a list and will try to delete all odd members.
I am having a slight problem in my code.Here is my code

```
void removeOdds(list<int>& myvector)
{
    for(list<int>::iterator p=myvector.begin(); p !=myvector.end();p++)
    {
        if(*p%2 !=0)
        {
            list<int>::iterator temp=myvector.erase(p);
            p=temp;
            if(p !=myvector.begin())
                p--;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that If I pass a list containing 1 3 5 2 6 7 for example. After deleting 1, it obviously skips to 5, and does not look at 3.
How can I fix this, because that p++ increments, and p-- does not happen because I am at the beginning.

Comment: [OT]: I would avoid to call the param `myvector` for a `std::list` (as `std::vector` exists). myInts`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it would be to use [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove). This removes elements from the list based on a unary predicate. For example,

```
myvector.remove_if([](int n) { return n % 2 != 0; });
```

The best way to work with the "STL"<sup>*</sup> is to know what is in it.

For pre-C++11 implementations (such as the actual STL), you can pass a function:

```
bool is_odd(int n) { return n % 2 != 0; }

myvector.remove_if(is_odd);
```

---

<sup>*"STL" means the STL but this also applies the C++ standard library</sup>

Comment: That is true, but I am trying to get familiar with the concept and learn how can I manipulate the iterators and such, so I would like to do it without the remove_if function.

Comment: @user1335175 You said you were "trying to learn how to work with STL", so.

Answer (score 2):

Method erase returns iterator to the next element after deleted. So the usual approach to such a task is the following

```
void removeOdds( std::list<int> &myvector )
{
    for ( auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end();  )
    {
        if ( *it % 2 !=0 )
        {
            it = myvector.erase( it );
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

As for your code then the loop statement always increases the iterator

```
for(list<int>::iterator p=myvector.begin(); p !=myvector.end();p++)
                                                               ^^^^
```

Take into account that class `std::list` has methods `remove` and `remove_if` that erase all elements that satisfy the given criteria.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the both approaches

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void removeOdds( std::list<int> &myvector )
{
    for ( auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end();  )
    {
        if ( *it % 2 !=0 )
        {
            it = myvector.erase( it );
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7 };

    for ( auto x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    removeOdds( l );

    for ( auto x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    l = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7 };

    for ( auto x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    l.remove_if( []( int x ) { return x % 2; } );

    for ( auto x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 3 5 2 6 7 
2 6 
1 3 5 2 6 7 
2 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found one way to do this, and that was to move p++ from for loop declaration into inside it, like this.

```
void removeOdds(list<int>& myvector)
{
    for(list<int>::iterator p=myvector.begin(); p !=myvector.end();)
    {
        if(*p%2 !=0)
        {
            list<int>::iterator temp=myvector.erase(p);
            p=temp;
        }
        else
            p++;
    }
}
```

Now I am curious if I can do this and still keep my for loop intact.

Comment: What do you mean with "keep my for loop intact"?

Comment: Note that you can directly do `p = myvector.erase(p);`.

Comment: By saying keep the for loop intact, I meant keep it the same way as I showed in my question.

Comment: @user1335175  Your loop is less efficient than calling `remove_if`.   Also, the `remove_if` is guaranteed to work correctly without further inspection, any competent C++ programmer understands what it does, etc.  On the other hand,  someone has to go over your loop and test it, see if there are any pitfalls, etc, before it can be deemed as sound.  Thus there really is very little need to "keep the loop intact".  It doesn't buy you anything keeping the loop, and can only cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're learning, you better forget the 'C' way of  doing things and jump directly into C++11.

Here's your code in modern C++

```
void removeOdds(vector<int>& myvector)
{
    auto new_end = std::remove_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
     [](const auto& value){ return value%2 !=0 }
    );    
    myvector.erase(new_end, myvector.end());
}
```

As far as your code goes, you can improve readability a lot just by using auto
Please not that it is risky to remove elements while looping on a container. You're usually fine with a vector, but when you start using other data structures things get more nasty.

Comment: it is the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, given that a more efficient 1-liner exists. Also, there's no `std::erase`, but maybe you mean `myvector.erase`.

Comment: yeah you're right, it's vector.erase. However please provide an example of more efficient one liners. This has linear complexity, which I am quite sure you can't beat given the nature of the problem given.

Comment: Well, there's my answer, which was the first one posted here. It doesn't matter if the *time complexity* is linear. You have to do two passes, one to re-arrange the list, the other to remove the elements. There's no reason for that with `std::list`.

Comment: I will suggest you to time the two solutions. The one with list will be slower by orders of magnitude. Also, there are no two passes, the erase does nothing more than changing some internal status on the vector, it does not need to scan the vector again. Lists have really, really, really limited useful scope, but for some reason that's what they teach at school/uni and people are stuck with them.

Comment: What? We're removing elements from a list here. That is what the question is about, and that is what your poor solution is attempting in an unnecessarily complicated way.

Comment: I assumed it was a vector since OP called it myVector, which would be indeed a better solution.

Comment: "STL list, delete all the odd numbers"